# C# Split string on 'þ', not on 'th'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6.1

In C# I have a string that I need to split on the character 'þ'.  The problem is that the string is split on 'th' as well.

```
string dataline = 'is thisþis that';
string[] dataFields;
dataFields = dataline.Split('þ');
```

This will result in the output

```
'is '
'is'
'is '
'at'
```

What I want is

```
'is this'
'is that'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I am not seeing the same thing, my output is as you want it. What culture settings do you have? [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ECHxza)

Comment: Dutch (Belgium)

Comment: Works for me as well, like @DavidG suggests this has to do with your culture settings. My culture is setup English US.

Comment: This is a culture setting issue.

Comment: Note that your first line is also a syntax error, you should be using double quotes.

Comment: Works fine with German culture sttings [de-De]..

Comment: That's the letter thorn, it started to get replaced by "th" in English around the 14th century.  Check the machine's clock, consider dataline.Replace("þ", "|").Split('|') as a workaround.

Comment: Hm, good advice but no explanation. It works fine for belgian culture settings as well..

Comment: Is that stuff about the machine clock a joke?  Because if not I don't understand, but if it's a joke it's a good one.

Comment: Sorry bout the syntax error, this is not in the application

Comment: I don't understand why dataline.Replace("þ", "|").Split('|') is different, but this solved the issue.